# Last value by type with _id relation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a collection of Event containing a `type` that can be `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and a `createdAt` date. Each event is related to an other collection called RTS.

I want to gather for each Rts, the last event of each type.

**Problem using my soluce :**

The problem is, I have to describe each `types` one by one in order to make it work. Is there any solution to have dynamical key creation induced by the `type` value ?

**Here is what I get now :**

1. I sort the data
2. Group by `idRTS` whch contains the link to the second collection. For each type, push the values inside of a specific array.
3. Remove the null values from the types arrays.
4. Keep the first value only `(the most updated)`.
5. Makes the data presentable.

---

```
[
  {
    $sort: {
      idRTS: -1,
      createdAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$idRTS',
      type0: {
        $push: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                '$type', 0
              ]
            },
            then: '$$ROOT',
            else: null
          }
        }
      },
      type5: {
        $push: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                '$type', 5
              ]
            },
            then: '$$ROOT',
            else: null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: '$_id',
      type0: {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$type0',
          'as': 'd',
          'cond': {
            '$ne': [
              '$$d', null
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      type5: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$type5',
          as: 'd',
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              '$$d', null
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: '$_id',
      type0: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          '$type0', 0
        ]
      },
      type5: {
        '$arrayElemAt': [
          '$type5', 0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$match` type in 0 or 5
- `$sort` by `idRTS` and `createdAt` in descending order
- `$group` by both `idRTS` and `createdAt` field and get first object, this will get first document of both type
- `$group` by `idRTS` and make array of both types, in k(key) and v(value) format
- `$project` to convert `type` array to object using `$objectToArray`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { type: { $in: [0, 5] } } },
  {
    $sort: {
      idRTS: -1,
      createdAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        idRTS: "$idRTS",
        type: "$type"
      },
      type: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.idRTS",
      type: {
        $push: {
          k: { $toString: "$type.type" },
          v: "$type"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { type: { $arrayToObject: "$type" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_PqGrpzdmU2)